# Loading dynamic images from SQLite

Tags: android, image

I returned a string from SQLite table and want to load image from the drawable folder. Is it possible?

For example :

```
String name = sql.getName(1); //name is now Barney
img.setImageResource(R.drawable.name);
```

Is it possible to load it this way?

I've tried.

```
int imageid = getResources().getIdentifier("com.tes.test.main:drawable/" + name.toLowerCase(), null, null);
img.setImageResource(imageid);
```

Doesn't work either. :(

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, I've found it.

```
String image = "test";
int pimageid = getResources().getIdentifier("com.yourpackage.name:drawable/"+image,null,null);
img.setImageResource(pimageid);
```

Answer (score 0):

1st. A few weeks ago i used this for a VideoView. Must be nearly the same for pictures.

In my place i stored the videos in the /raw folder.

```
mVideoView.setVideoPath("android.resource://your-package-name/raw/"+videoName);
```

2nd. Why don't you save the picture into the database and read it from there? 
like this:

```
byte[] blob = cursor.getBlob(2);
```

Comment: Is your videoName a String?
Because when I use name as a String, it gives an error.
`img.setImageResource("android.resource://your-package-name/raw/"+name);`
It says it must be a int.