# setImageResource from generate file path

Tags: android, imageview, filepath

Hey guys I have the following code. I am basically recalling at intent and generating a number depending on the button that is pressed, I want to display a certain image.

```
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    int number = intent.getIntExtra("BUTTON NUMBER", 1);
    ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);

    String resource = "R.raw.img" + number;
    id = Integer.parseInt(resource);
    image.setImageResource(id);
```

However the code doesn't seem to be working, the application crashes with the following error:

> E/AndroidRuntime(12872): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start
>   activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.example.myapp/com.example.myapp.SecondActivity}:
>   java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "R.raw.img1"

Any ideas? I thought that I have alraedy converter the string into an integer?

Answer (score 0):

first of all you can not parse "R.raw.img1" as an integer. Thats why you get an `java.lang.NumberFormatException` here.

You are trying to access the resource with id "R.raw.img1" - this is an generated id. See Project -> gen -> [packageName] -> R.java. 
So "R.raw.img1" is the name of the generated id (integer). Accessing the integer the way you trying to do it, isn`t possible. 
Try

```
int resID = getResources().getIdentifier("img"+number, "raw", getPackageName());
```

This way you should get the correct id.

Answer (score 0):

try following:

```
int id = getResources().getIdentifier("android.resource://com.example.myapp/raw/img"+number,null,null);
img.setImageResource(id);
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11178670/loading-dynamic-images-from-sqlite)

Answer (score 0):

do it like this:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
int number = intent.getIntExtra("BUTTON NUMBER", 1);
ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);

int resID = getResources().getIdentifier("img"+number, "raw", getPackageName());
image.setImageResource(resID);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is very much simple code and is working fine for me.
    You directly can set Resource with its id to an ImageView as shown below.

```
 ImageView img=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgView);
        img.setImageResource(R.raw.calendar);
```

Code:

```
package packageName;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ImageView img=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgView);
        img.setImageResource(R.raw.calendar);

    }
}
```

Thanks..